# Running non-idempotent functions with HTTP call on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using a Google Cloud Function to run a function off an HTTP trigger. The code itself is non-idempotent, which is expected and desired for us as it's using an external API.

However, quick and repeated triggers of the cloud function yields the same output repeatedly (generally while there is 1 active instance), and we need the output to be different every time the function is triggered.

Unsure if this is due to instance caching or something else, but is there any known workaround to ensure that every time the cloud function is HTTP triggered we get a new output, even when triggered seconds apart?

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking for different output. Where is your code that creates the output? Please read this guide on how to create a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check if you are updating any global variables when the function is triggered. If they are, you need to stop doing that

Comment: What your code is doing? Did it keep global value in memory and reply it everytime? Please share your code (or a small piece to reproduce the issue)